# All permutations c++ with vector<int> and backtracking

Tags: c++, vector, permutation, backtracking

I'm trying generate all permutations of an vector to training backtracking technique but my code don't work for all vectors (works to size to vectors)

my code :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void permutations(int s,vector<int> v){
    if(s>=v.size())
        return;
    if( v.size()==0)
        cout<<endl;
    cout<<v[s]<<" ";
    vector<int> k = v;

    k.erase(k.begin()+s);

    for(int i =0;i<k.size();i++)
        return permutations(i,k);

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
    for(int i =0;i<v.size();i++){
        permutations(i,v);
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think is because when my recursive function find return they break the for but maybe I 'm wrong someone can tell my what's the problem and how can I correct it please.

Comment: There is `std::next_permutation()` you might want to use...

Comment: That `return` in a for loop makes little sense

Comment: Please note:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simple way is to use standard algorithm: [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

```
void print(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    for (int e : v) {
        std::cout << " " << e;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
    // vector should be sorted at the beginning.

    do {
        print(v);
    } while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/O4KhFh)